# Customizing Devise with Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm using Rails 4.0.0 and Devise 3.0.2 and trying to configure Devise with Strong Parameters following [this instruction](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) within the Devise README.

I wrote code like this in the `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :nick
  end
end
```

Then I visited `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`. I got a `NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new`, which says:

> undefined method `<<' for {}:ActionController::Parameters`

and points to the exact line where I wrote `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :nick`

Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried exactly the same code and get the same error. `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)` returns an empty hash, so it's not possible to call `<<` method on that.

I've submitted [an issue][1], you can follow that.


  [1]: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2574

Comment: @RafałCieślak Thank you for your confirmation, I'll follow the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Jose Valim said](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2574), it's Devise 3.1.0.rc feature, that's why it doesn't work. You have to use other syntaxes that are in README.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      ...
      before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?   
      ...
      def configure_permitted_parameters
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| 
            u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :nick) 
         }
      end
```

It works for me! :D

Comment: Does this go in the model?

Comment: I put in ApplicationController: 
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

Answer (score 4):

An issue exactly matches your problem : [#2574 : devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :something raises an error](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2574).

In fact, the method to add custom fields to strong parameters like that is a new feature coming with Devise 3.1.

Since the current version in Rubygems.org is `3.0.3`, you can't use this method in your rails project for now. You'll have to override the defaults like that :

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

But if you really need to, you can edit your *Gemfile* and replace this line

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.3'
```

with this one :

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'master'
```

Then you can easily add your custom fields like that :

```
# Single field
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :first_name
# Multiple fields at a time
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name]
```

But **be warned**, currently this is a **Release Candidate** : `3.1.0 RC1`

Comment: it's always the little details...would be nice if they mention this in the readme for poor github noobs like me...FWIW the ONLY thing that worked (tried a few different examples across the web) is putting my attrs in the u.permit group like Carlos mentions above.